# how to replace login button to logout button after login on welcome page in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to replace my login button to logout on our home page but i have no idea's what i do on my welcome page ofter successful login 
my login page shown on below
login.php

```
<form action="loginVerification.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <center><a href="#">Forget Password?</a></center>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
</div>    
<div class="col-sm-4">
<button type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login" value="login">Log In</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
</div>
```

everythings or okay but i want to a idea how to replace login to logout button
or both are differents header .

that is my loginVerification.php page are

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))
 {
    # code...

// Start the session
session_start();

include('include/dbConfig.php');


$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['pwd'];

$sql="SELECT * from users where Email = '$email' AND Password = '$password'"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($row['Email']==$email && $row['Password']==$password) 
{
        header("Location: Functional_token.html");

}

else
{
    echo "<script>window.alert('Email or Password incorrect')</script>";
}
}
?>
```

code for session is as below .
please give advice

```
<?php
session_start();
$username= $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$email = $_SESSION['Email'];
$country=$_SESSION['Country'];
?>
```

Comment: after successful login start SESSION. when sesion is set display LOGOUT button else display LOGIN button.

Comment: you are storing UNENCRYPTED passwords in your database? Everything is NOT ok!

Comment: @DevsiOdedra he's using token based auth by the look of it, so it's a stateless app with no sessions.

Comment: @delboy1978uk how can I fix this

Comment: @manishkumaryadav firstly, are you creating a stateless app or not? Session is the answer if you aren't! What is this functional token?

Comment: @delboy1978uk function_token is the name of the home page  where i am trying redirect my page ofter login

Comment: fair enough then, so a standard website and not an API. In that case check the answers below for a solution based on `$_SESSION`

Answer (score -1):

i will try to help you, first please add [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function in the top of your home page

your login or homepage code may looks like this :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == 'true')
    {
        ?>
        <form action="your_logout_page.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login" value="login">Log Out</button>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <form action="loginVerification.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <center><a href="#">Forget Password?</a></center>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>    
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login" value="login">Log In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

And for your login verification :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pwd']))
{
    include('include/dbConfig.php');

    // filter input from user : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pwd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // please note that plain text stored password is not a good practice and please use prepared statement
    // for further reading : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
    // for further reading : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
    // for further reading : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
    $sql="SELECT * from users where Email = '$email' AND Password = '$password'"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row['Email']==$email && $row['Password']==$password) 
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'true';
        header("Location: Functional_token.html");
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>window.alert('Email or Password incorrect')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

and [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) for your logout page :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();

    if(ini_get("session.use_cookies"))
    {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
    }

    session_destroy();
    // change this to your homepage location for redirect
    header("location: index.php");
    die();
?>
```

I add comment in the code, and I hope this will give you some idea about session.

Answer (score -2):

Make it if condition, if session not running make it login, else logout.

```
<?php if(SESSION['id']) { ?><button name="Logout"> <?php } else { ?> <button name="Login"> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: if it's a stateless app using token based auth (`header("Location: Functional_token.html");`) then there are NO sessions.

Comment: <?php  if(SESSION['id']) {   ?><button name="Logout"> <?php } else {  
 ?> <button name="Login"> <?php }  ?>

Comment: You have to use session

Comment: i have make  a session but don't know where i add my code                                        <?php
session_start();
$username= $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$email = $_SESSION['Email'];
$country=$_SESSION['Country'];
?>